# Kenmore Elite range safe to use after melting LED bulb?

Tags: gas, oven, light-bulb

I ran the self clean cycle that melted the LED lightbulb and I can't clean the resulting metal out of the socket. I'd like to know if the oven is safe to use with that residue and effects of the melted bulb? There is a very fragile skin running down the wall of the oven wall that disintegrates with a slight touch but the main part of it doesn't come off.

Comment: A picture of the damage, as well as the exact model number might help us help you. You can simply [edit] those into your question.

Comment: I can't seem to resize the image. It's down to 6xxkb but says it still too large to post.

Comment: Wait, is this an OEM LED that is part of the oven? Or did you use a random screw-in LED for the oven light?

Comment: Not OEM. I wanted a brighter light.

Comment: you can't use standard LED light bulbs in an oven ... they are usually made of plastic

Comment: Post the image directly to imgur.com, then share the link here. This site does have a rather silly 2mb image size limit, which many phone cameras regularly exceed...

Comment: @jsotola Even if they weren’t plastic, you would be hard pressed to find an LED bulb at a reasonable price that’s rated for more than about 125 degrees Celsius, and you want a rating of _at least_ 300 degrees Celsius for a culinary oven (possibly higher depending on what you want to do in it). High temperature integrated circuits are _really_ expensive and are almost invariably specialty parts (and thus hard to find as well as being expensive).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn yes, I've been building a couple of merely 200°C very simple electronic setups in work recently, and even that's a pain.  A lot of what I use for that is max 250°C (PTFE insulation) and any tin-based solder will melt below 232°C.  If I absolutely needed LED illumination in a hot environment, I'd be designing from scratch, with the LEDs outside either through windows or (glass) fibre optics

Answer (score 16):

You'll need to heat the plastic enough to soften it, then unscrew the remaining bulb parts. Turn off the breaker before that second step.

As long as plastic remains in the oven it'll stink and could pose health risks. You'll want to scrape it all away with a razor blade and other tools.

Use only bulbs labeled for oven use. LEDs probably never qualify.

Comment: Yes. LED bulbs won't be anywhere near taking that heat. I've desoldered LEDs in my oven, and LED bulbs contain LEDs and other components soldered to  circuit boards.  Even with no plastic they'd die at baking temperatures (though maybe not instantly as oven bulbs are slightly protected from the heat.  It would just about be possible to make an LED bulb that could take that kind of heat but it would cost a fortune.

Answer (score 9):

One important point first: **Turn off the power while cleaning up**.

You're likely to be poking metal tools into the light fitting which, depending on where you live and how your oven is built, will have 120V or 230V on it.  And your other hand could well be grounded via the oven chassis, making for one of the worst ways to get shocked.

But cleaning up is definitely feasible.

I would start *cold* in the hopes of the plastic being brittle.  If the oven wasn't perfectly clean to start with, removal will be easier.  You'll need scraping tools and long-nose pliers (the latter to get the base out).

I have helped clean melted plastic out of an oven after a friend put a plastic container in there.  That was more than you have, but near the front.  It took a couple of hours of scraping and scrubbing to get it out.

If yours has a self-cleaning coating, that may get damaged in removing the plastic.  Some warmth to soften it will allow the use of gentler tools (wooden probably).

Finally once it's all gone and you've got the bulb cover back in place properly, run the self clean cycle again before cooking.  Probably with the kitchen well ventilated.  This is to burn off any residue before food gets in there - but I do mean residue and not as a way of getting rid of the bulk.